# SaveFileDialog is not opening after VSTO installed

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have custom ribbon as part of VSTO for Excel. It should create some data - this part works well, and then save it to XML file. All works good on my dev PC. But while I am trying to install VSTO to another PC, SaveFileDialog isn't opening nor any exception throw.

Part of my code which is in static class called in ribbon class:

```
            XmlWriterSettings xmlSet = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xmlSet.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            xmlSet.Indent = true;
            xmlSet.IndentChars = "    ";

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PromoticClass));

            try
            {
                SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                saveDialog.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";

                if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(saveDialog.FileName, xmlSet))
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(writer, xmlDoc);
                    }

                    MsgBox done = new MsgBox("Promotic XML file generated.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MsgBox fail = new MsgBox("Promotic XML generation failed.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MsgBox exMsg = new MsgBox(ex.ToString());
            }
```

Am I missing something to install on all others PC to have this extension working?

ps: I have checked Trust center in Excel and nothing is disabled, so this shouldn't be the issue.

Thank You for help

Comment: Add a `MessageBox.Show("Foobar!");` as first line of your action code that is executed upon Ribbon button click. Is it shown? Add some logging mechanism to find out where exactly your code fails and why. Cannot tell from this snippet.

Comment: Two basic reasons.  A dialog must always have an owner, ideally it finds the Excel main window back.  If not then it might open correctly but appear behind the Excel window, you just can't see it.  The other is that it injects a lot of code into a process, the shell extensions that are installed on the machine.  Programmers tend to have a lot of them, not always well-behaved.  You can chase that down by enabling unmanaged debugging, or trying it on another machine that is relatively clean.